# Why are different colours used for the homepage tab borders?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, design

The main tabs on the Super User homepage use two different colours for the borders:

[image: SU]

On Stack Overflow, a single border colour is used:

[image: SO]

Similarly, on Meta Super User it looks like:

[image: MSU]

Is the different colour scheme for Super User (and for Server Fault) intentional? If so, why?

For convenience, here's how the [current](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06cz4.png), [all #CCCCCC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYzFy.png) and [all #999999](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDWav.png) schemes would compare. I think the "[all #CCCCCC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYzFy.png)" version looks more consistent.

Comment: I assume the `.subheader` styles differ between sites and the color for `#tabs a.youarehere` don't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have pushed a fix for this. The change will be live after our next production build.